# Are header files different for x86 and ARM for webrtc?

Tags: webrtc

I need to use webrtc in my Android native application.
After downloading the source for webrtc, here are the primary steps for building webrtc:

```
$ export GYP_DEFINES="OS=Android..."
$ gclient runhooks
$ ninja -C out/Release AppRTCDemo
```

The target architecture, ARM or x86, must be defined through `GYP_DEFINES`.

I need to decide if I must create platform-specific directories for webrtc source files. Does `gclient runhooks` modify webrtc source code in any way? Regards.

Comment: Are you wanting to cross-compile `ARM` and `x86`?

Comment: I just want to run ninja on AppRTCDemo to make sure that everything works. After that, I wish to copy the directory structure to my jni directory for Android and create a makefile (Android.mk). Thanks.

Comment: `gclient runhooks` shouldn't modify the source, as it's a compile time command. The resulting built files will be different for whatever platform it's built for, but the original source should remain the same. I think developers would be quickly agitated if the compiler went messing with their original source code.